# How to perform Change Point Analysis using R.NET

Tags: c#, r, r.net

How to perform Change Point Analysis using R.NET. I am using below code

```
REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
double[] data = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
NumericVector vector = engine.CreateNumericVector(data);
engine.SetSymbol("mydatapoints", vector);
engine.Evaluate("library(changepoint)");
engine.Evaluate("chpoints = cpt.mean(mydatapoints, method="BinSeg")");
DynamicVector result = engine.Evaluate("x<-cpts(chpoints)").AsVector(); ;
engine.Dispose();
```

I am receiving below error on `engine.Evaluate("library(changepoint)");`

> Error in library(changepoint) : there is no package called
>   'changepoint'

**Edit # 1**

The `changepoint` package is supposed to be installed explicitly, it is not there by default. Installed it using RGui -> Packages -> Load package.

Now the error has been changed to

> Status Error for chpoints = cpt.mean(mydatapoints, method=”BinSeg”)  :
>   unexpected input

**Edit # 2**

After fixing first two errors, the following one appears on second Evaluate statement.

> Error in BINSEG(sumstat, pen = pen.value, cost_func = costfunc,
>   minseglen = minseglen,  :    Q is larger than the maximum number of
>   segments 4

**The same error appears on R as well using these commands**

```
value.ts <- c(29.89, 29.93, 29.72, 29.98)
chpoints = cpt.mean(value.ts, method="BinSeg")
```

Comment: does this command work when you type it purely in R?

Comment: @MongZhu I don't know R there are examples but those are generating the series. I want to work with my given series.

Comment: I am talking about the error message when using `library(changepoint)`. Do you get the same message when you type this command into the R shell?

Comment: @MongZhu Yes there is a same error on just typing this command

Comment: have a look on [this article](https://github.com/STAT545-UBC/Discussion/issues/250). it possibly can help

Comment: @MongZhu, oops, the `changepoint` package is supposed to be installed, it is not there by default. I have added it and now the error has been changed

Comment: then it would be time to update your post :)

Comment: @MongZhu yes did it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data points are supposed to be converted in Time Series.

```
REngine.SetEnvironmentVariables();
REngine engine = REngine.GetInstance();
double[] data = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
NumericVector vector = engine.CreateNumericVector(data);
engine.Evaluate("library(changepoint)");
engine.SetSymbol("values", vector);
engine.Evaluate("values.ts = ts(values, frequency = 12, start = c(2017, 1))");
engine.Evaluate("chpoints = cpt.mean(values.ts, method=\"BinSeg\")");
var result = engine.GetSymbol("chpoints");
engine.Dispose();
```

**Now looking for how to get the results back in C#, `chpoints` or result of `plot(chpoints)`**

Comment: You can mark your question as answered and then post another question. .

Comment: @42- yes of course, but not allowing to accept it right now. Another question has already been posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567909/retrieve-result-from-r-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in your calling code but rather in your use of R (as you apparently now realize.) So the labeling of this as something to do with rdotnet or c-sharp seems misleading:

```
mydatapoints <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 )
library(changepoint);
chpoints = cpt.mean(mydatapoints, method="BinSeg");
#Error in BINSEG(sumstat, pen = pen.value, cost_func = costfunc, minseglen = minseglen,  : 
#  Q is larger than the maximum number of segments 4
```

I'm not sure what you intended. Change-point analysis generally  requires paired datapoints ... x-y and all that jazz. And giving R regression functions perfectly linear data is also unwise. It often causes non-invertible matrices.

I suggest you search with https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+changepoint to find a simple bit of code to build into your REngine calling scheme.

Comment: you are right, data points are needed to be converted to Time Series. Posted my answer. Now looking for how to get the result in C#